# Не работает ссылка на приложение для создания тайлов. Где взять рабочую?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

[Ссылка в документации](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/archive/doc/jsapi/1.x/dg/concepts/ymapstiler.html) не работает. Как тогда создать тайлы? Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужно создать пользовательский [Layer](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_map)

В песочнице Яндекса, кстати, есть [пример](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_map) с комментариями